# jQuery class within class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

how do I find the inner div here?

`$container.find('.outer .inner')`

is just going to look for a div with `class="outer inner"`, is that correct?

so I tried

`$container.find('.outer > .inner')`

but that doesn't seem to be working.

**Edit:**

I know its easy to find with something like

`$container.find('.outer').find('.inner')`

but I'm looking for the kind of single selector syntax which reads better imho.

Comment: How is `$container` defined? Besides that, should use single selectors whenever possible. It is way easier to read if you do not have to search for the different selector parts all over the place.

Comment: "but I'm looking for the kind of single selector syntax which reads better imho." You should prefer the `.find(...)` way because it will be faster the more complex your selector gets or if you use an selector which is not supported by the browser. In this case sizzle will be used for selection which is/could be really slow in comparison to a splitted selector with `.find(...)`.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> is just going to look for a div with class="outer inner", is that correct?

No, `'.outer .inner'` will look for all elements with the *.inner* class that also have an element with the *.outer* class as an ancestor.  `'.outer.inner'` (no space) would give the results you're thinking of.

`'.outer > .inner'` will look for immediate children of an element with the *.outer* class for elements with the *.inner* class.

Both `'.outer .inner'` and `'.outer > .inner'` should work for your example, although the selectors are fundamentally different and you should be wary of this.

Comment: I had another mistake in my code which led me to think my selector wasn't working, but it was after all. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 39):

For this html:

```
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

This selector should work:

```
$('.outer > .inner')
```