# jscript 'type' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to implement the following logic on javascript.

If type is 'bankAccountTypeId' get all fields with the same className as field using $(field.className) then use .each to loop through each result compare field.value with $(this).val() and use alert to show an error message if they are different (break if fail).

function onChange_productListField(field, type) {

```
  if (HimmsJSUtil.elementHasClass(field, 'DC')) {

        var allProductGroupFields = $(".DC."+type);

        var value = field.value;

        if (field.options) {

              value = HimmsJSUtil.getSelectedDropDownOption(field);

        }

        allProductGroupFields.each(function(index) {

              if ($(this).attr("id") != field.id

                          && !$(this).val()) {

                    $(this).val(value);

              }

        });

  } else {



        /* implement the logic here */

  }
```

}

My question is , how would the type attribute work, within this logic?

Comment: sorry but i can't understand nothing about your question as well as from your code! Can you explane what you are trying to do? and post html code, this will make things more faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firsly let's make clear that jscript is not javascript and "type" in your code is not attribute but just a parameter of the function.

```
var allProductGroupFields = $(".DC."+type);
```

The above line uses jQuery to select a group of elements having classes "DC" and "bankAccountTypeId" at the same time where type is "bankAccountTypeId". Such a code can be used in a structure like this:

```
<div class="whatever">
    <input type="text" class="DC bankAccountTypeId" />
    <input type="text" class="DC userId" />
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344">
        jQuery multiple class selector
    <a>
</div>
```

**Extra:**
For a structure like this

```
<div class="DC">
    <input type="text" class="bankAccountTypeId" />
    <input type="text" class="userId" />
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767512">
        jQuery class within class selector
    <a>
</div>
```

the selector line must be changed to

```
var allProductGroupFields = $(".DC ."+type);
```

Comment: Actually, that would produce the selector `".DC.bankAccountTypeId"` which would not select with the structure shown. For that structure you need to produce the selector `".DC .bankAccountTypeId"` or `".DC > .bankAccountTypeId"`. Or change the structure to have `<div class="DC bankAccountTypeId">`.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector) says how to make intersection in selectors. There is no space for intersection.

Comment: That's correct. Which is why you would need to change the structure, or the selector. See http://jsfiddle.net/CmVPv/ for example