# Do not append element if it exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using `.length` to check if div with class exist and if exist `.append` should not add a new div.

https://jsfiddle.net/uhvL1hfx/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="field">
    This div exist, so .append should not add a new div, should add only if this div does not exist.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
if( $("div.container div.inner div.field").length ){
    $("div.container div.inner").append("<div>But for some reason it still adds it.</div>");
}
```

But it still appends a new div. Should append if `div.field` does not exist.

Comment: A simple `!` before your selector should do you some good.

Comment: Suggested post for jQuery selector: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767512/jquery-class-within-class-selector.  Also as Wild Beard has noted, I believe using (!$('selector')) instead of .length would be preferred.  [edit:  I stand corrected, that .length is still necessary]

Comment: @KyleBallard You still need `.length`. A selector is always truthy.

Comment: @KyleBallard Wild Beard isn't suggesting to use `!` *instead* of using `.length`, he's suggesting using it *in addition* to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition should be `$("div.container div.inner div.field").length == 0` to check if there is no other element with the class in the container div before appending it.

```
if( $("div.container div.inner div.field").length == 0){
    $("div.container div.inner").append("<div class=\"field\">But for some reason it still adds it.</div>");
}
```

I also gave the class of `field` to the div you are appending so that the next time the code is executing it the condition will fail since there is now a div with the given class present in the container div.

Comment: Does this work only for one element on the page or for multiple? I got this working on jsfiddle, but can't reproduce on actual website.

Comment: The condition here is checking if a div of class field exist in the container div. if you want to use multiple element you will need to check with their `ids` and not with a common class

Answer (score 0):

Because your code already has the div.field so length === 1
what you want is like this:

```
if( $("div.container div.inner div.field").length > 0){


}else{
    $("div.container div.inner").append("<div class=\"field\">But for some reason it still adds it.</div>");
}
```

Comment: ...or you could use just == 0